# Magento 2.3.5-p2: Send store emails from different email IDs

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

I've installed the SMTP extension from Mageplaza [link](https://docs.mageplaza.com/smtp-m2/). And configured it to send from **we.care@xyz.com**, as below.

[image]

However it allows for only one email to be configured, as a result despite adding different "Sender Emails" as shown below, all emails get sent out from only the email (**we.care@xyz.com**) that was configured under the SMTP extension.

[image]

All sales emails are set to send from Sale Representative (**sales@xyz.com**)
Whilst new account creation, newsletter signup are set to send from **we.care@xyz.com**

But all emails are being sent from **we.care@xyz.com**

How do I get emails to be sent out from **sales@xyz.com** as well as we.care@xyz.com?

Answer (score 0):

Running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` clearing the cache seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you got that sorted, be sure to accept your own answer!